# How to extract data of a file that is pointed by another file

Tags: python, file-io

I am using python and I have a file called "indexes"
that has the following structure:

```
class1 fileNameX
class2 fileNameY
class3 fileNameZ
```

which is a collection of classes associated to file name.

fileNameX is a matlab file that has 2 matrices. I can extract the data and concatenate it directly from fileNameX as follows:

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('filenameX')
var1 = mat['dataL']
var2 = mat['dataR']
var3=np.concatenate((var1, var2), axis=0)
var4 = var3.reshape(1,387200)
```

My question is how can automatically get the concatenated form as in var4 for every single filename in the indexes file.

The output that I want is a vector "A" containing the classes, that I can do this myself, the problem is to get vector "B" on the form of var4 for every single filename.

Thank you and any help is appreciate it.

EDIT: the classes are numbers (1-100), and I have many files pointed by the indexes file. Is there a way to automatically load all of them not one by one?
Finally the vector A and matrix B are desired to be numpy arrays.

Comment: Is that the actual structure of `indexes`? Does it really have the parentheses in each line?

Comment: No, I updated the correct form. is only a "space" separated file.

Comment: So this is a question about how to read file content right?

Comment: Yes! pointed by another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = []
B = []
with open('indexes') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue
        className, fname = line.split(None,1)
        A.append(className)
        mat = scipy.io.loadmat('filenameX')
        var = np.concatenate((mat['dataL'], mat['dataR']), axis=0).reshape(1,387200)
        B.append(var)
```

Now, `A[i]` contains the class name of the `i`th line in `indexes`, while `B[i]` contains the matlab matrix (`var4` in your code) of the file name indicated in the `i`th line in `indexes`

Comment: Thank you this works, can you please take a look at the edit part I made to the original question? I am trying to generalize this. Thanks!

Comment: @user3025898 My solution already handles most of your edit. The only thing that is not handled is that `A` and `B` are `list`s, not `numpy.array`s. This is easily fixed with `A,B = np.array(A), np.array(B)`

Comment: I have a problem with the code line "mat = scipy.io.loadmat('filenameX')" it returns, IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filenameX.mat' unless I put the name of one of the files. it seems that your code is not generalizing for all the filenames in the list it takes into consideration just one. can you help solve this?

Comment: I just run your code and it repeats saving the values of filenameX only in all the rows of B. can you help fix this?

Comment: solution:         mat = scipy.io.loadmat(fname,appendmat=True)

Comment: Dear inspectorG4dget. I have problems appending numpy arrays to python lists, the output list are not in the format that I want. is there a way to append numpy arrays to numpy arrays in the for loop without using python lists?

Comment: @user3025898: I suppose you could do `B = np.array()` and `np.append((B,var), axis=0)`

Comment: The problem I find is to find the equivalent in Numpy for B = [] if I use B = np.empty() the program returns TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found

Comment: @user3025898: does `B = np.array()` not work for you?

Comment: B = np.array() returns TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found

Comment: @user3025898: `B = np.array([])`

Comment: so I have B = np.array([]) instead of B = [] at the beginning and B= np.append((B,var), axis=0) instead of  B.append(var), the program returns the following error: TypeError: append() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)

Comment: @user3025898: I'm out of ideas. I recommend making a fresh post to address a larger audience

Answer (score 0):

The regexp I used is not the most stringent (you could replace the first w+ for "class", but for the sake of flexibility I left it as any sequence of letters.

```
import re

#you would load this with open(indexfilename,"rt").read()
index_file_content = "(class 1, fileNameX)\n(class 2, fileNameY)\n(class 3, fileNameZ)"

files = re.findall("\(\w+\s+\d+,\s+(\w+)\)", filecontent)

# files == ['fileNameX', 'fileNameY', 'fileNameZ']
```

Comment: HI, the classes are numbers. I just edited the question. Thank you!